# Eventproblem Too few arguments to function

Tags: symfony, events

i have a problem with my Testproject, i tray to make Event, the function of this event is following, when the controller call the row with id 18 from the datebase, it will to call/dispach event, this event have to send email to a Email Adress.
the problem, i cannot call this event from my eventlistener, because i get the wrong:
Too few arguments to function App\customEvents\EmailEvent::SendEMail(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\Authentication\src\EventListener\EmailListener.php on line 15 and exactly 1 expected

Controller:

```
    namespace App\Controller;
    use App\Entity\Posts;
    use App\Repository\PostsRepository;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
    use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
    
    class EventoController extends AbstractController
    {
        #[Route('/evento', name: 'app_evento')]
        public function index(PostsRepository $Posts, EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher): Response
        {
              $todo=$Posts->find(18);
    
              $sendEmail=new \App\customEvents\EmailEvent;
              $eventDispatcher->dispatch($sendEmail, \App\customEvents\EmailEvent::NAME);
    
    
    
            return $this->render('evento/index.html.twig', [
                'getdaten' => $todo,
            ]);
        }
    }


EmailListener

    <?php
    namespace App\EventListener;
    use App\customEvents\EmailEvent;
    use Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface;
    
    class EmailListener
    {
        public function sendemailaktive( EmailEvent $MeinEmailEvent)
        {
          $MeinEmailEvent->SendEMail();
        }
    
    }


EmailEvent

    <?php
    namespace App\customEvents;
    use Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Mime\Email;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail;
    use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    
    class EmailEvent extends EventDispatcher
    {
        public const NAME = 'send.email';
    
        public function SendEMail(MailerInterface $mailer)
        {
          $email = (new Email())
          ->from('hello@asdasd.com')
          ->to('spam@muhkas.com')
          ->subject('Email From Send!')
          ->text('Sending emails is fun again!')
          ->html('<p>See Twig integration for better HTML integration!</p>');
          $mailer->send($email);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are expecting $mailer to be automatically injected into your sendEmail method but it won't be.  The only methods that automatically inject stuff are controller actions and there is a bunch of behind the scenes code to do that.  So study up a bit on the service container and inject $mailer into your listener's constructor.  A bit off-topic but events should not be sending emails.  Move the code to your listener.  You could have the event carry some data used for creating the email.

Comment: And maybe review the docs on the event dispatcher as well.  Event classes don't extend the EventDispatcher nor do you need to fool around with an event name.  The class name will suffice.